# How can I turn off specific messages in syntastic (vim)?

Tags: vim, syntastic

I'm trying to turn off some of the messages in syntastic.

For example, `SC20148` in bash files (it complains there's no shebang).

After looking through the documentation, it seemed that perhaps this might be done through:

```
let g:synstatic_quiet_messages = {
  \ 'type': 'syntax',
  \ 'regex': 'SC20148' }
```

However this doesn't seem to work.  How do I turn off specific messages?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Devil is in the details:

1. the variable is actually called `g:syntastic_quiet_messages`
2. the error is actually `SC2148`
3. you probably don't want to disable syntax messages.

Thus:

```
let g:syntastic_quiet_messages = { 'regex': 'SC2148' }
```

Or just:

```
let g:syntastic_sh_shellcheck_args = '-e SC2148'
```

Answer (score 4):

**Turn off multiple kinds of warnings in syntastic in vim:**

Add this line to your .vimrc

```
let g:syntastic_quiet_messages = { 'regex': 'SC2148\|SC1234\|SC6789' }
```

Also you can do it against the message itself like this:

```
let g:syntastic_quiet_messages = { "regex": 'superfluous-parens\|too-many-instance-attributes\|too-few-public-methods' }
```

Answer (score 3):

*Agree with accepted answer, but wished to add some extra context.*

You can run `:h syntastic_quiet_messages` to get the official docs with explanation of the commands.

You can use `syntastic_quiet_messages` or, if you have a particular filetype and checker, then use `syntastic_<filetype>_<checker>_quiet_messages`.

Here is a snippet from my `.vimrc`:

```
" keep some globals quiet
let g:syntastic_javascript_standard_quiet_messages = { 'regex': ['alert',
                                            \ 'localStorage',
                                            \ 'auth0js',
                                            \ 'auth0'] }
```

Above, I am keeping global errors quiet, and use an array to list more than one item. Only wish to apply this to `javascript` files, using the [standard style lint checker](https://standardjs.com/).